# XCode - why do I get a file not found?

Tags: xcode, urbanairship.com

I've added the Airship (from UrbanAirship) directory into my xcode project for my iPhone/iPad app.   In my "build settings>search paths>header search paths" and "build settings>search paths>library search paths", I'm pointing to those directories recursively.  I've also included the libuairship-1.2.1.a file3 into the required frameowrks/libraries.

When I go into my appdelegate.m and appdelegate.h, as soon as I type `#import "UA"`, it autocompletes for me `#import "UAirship.h"`.  So i assume this is great ,because i guess it means it knows the file exists!

but when I do a build, it Xcode complains that the file UAirship.h can not be foudn.  I tried typing #import "directoryname/UAirship.h", but it still can't find it.

How do i fix this problem?

[image: Screenshot depicting error message]

Comment: I tried all sort of solution mentioned below but none worked out. I'm getting red color for "libUAirship-1.1.0.a" framework in build phases.

Comment: If you've ended up on this question that's because you're good at following directions. The documentation for install is just wrong. Even their support team references this SO post. So this post is the official documentation now. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely means that the file is part of your project, but its path is incorrect (for whatever reason).  This will be visible in that if you locate the file in the project browser its name will be red.

Assuming that is the case you can select it and edit the files location properties, or delete it from the project and then add that file back again.

This can happen easily if you import or open projects from other systems.

Regards

Answer (score 9):

I am sure it is the path under - header search paths.

I just had it set to ../Airship/** and had the same problem you did.

Now that I changed it to ./Airship/** and it works fine.

I also had to import

```
#import "UAirship.h"
#import "UAPush.h"
#import "UAInbox.h"
#import "UAInboxUI.h"
```

in the application delegate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Kudos to you, user1006117 - removing that second '.' fixed my issue as well.

Comment: This should be the selected answer IMHO. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

For XCode 5.1 I had to set this to `./Airship` (recursive)

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me,

Delete Pod folder and Podfile.lock

then "pod install"

then "pod update”

Or sometimes, pod update and then pod install