# Property 'settings' not found on object of type 'id<CDVCommandDelegate>' in phonegap Urbanairship push notification configuration

Tags: ios, cordova, urbanairship.com

When trying to integrate the [phonegap urbanairship iOS plugin](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push) I get a build error as follows:
In file `PushNotificationPlugin.m`, `Property 'settings' not found on object of type 'id<CDVCommandDelegate>'`. How to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it had something to do with the library versions. This error was solved by upgrading phonegap to 2.9 and then adding the urbanairship plugin. The phonegap library upgrade was done using the cli.
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15165712/235273
I used the latest version of [urbanairship library](http://com.urbanairship.filereleases.s3.amazonaws.com/libUAirship-latest.zip) and linked with the `libUAirship-3.0.2.a` static file. The build then succeeds.